# Im trying to sort a list of Cities and their Temperature using a bubblesort

Tags: c++

Im fairly new to C++ and im trying to convert an int "city.temp[4]" to a string and then adding that to an already existing string "city.name[4]" which would then sort the cities and their temperatures based on low to high. The user is the one to name all four cities and assign them a temperature. The bubbleSort is working fine sorting the temperatures by them self but im not sure how to get the cities to follow along with their respective temperatures

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class City{
public:
    string name[4];
    int temp[4];

};
    
int main() {    
    City city;
    city.name[4];
    city.temp[4];
  
    cout << "           Please Input the name of 4 different cities and their temperature\n\n\n";

        for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){

            cout << " Input the name and temperature of city (" << i+1 << "): "; getline(cin, city.name[i]); cout << " "; cin >> city.temp[i];
            cin.ignore();    
        }
   
    int length = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < length - 1; j++){

            if(city.temp[j] > city.temp[j+1]){

                int hold = city.temp[j];
                city.temp[j] = city.temp[j+1];
                city.temp[j+1] = hold;
            }
        }
    }




    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)

        cout << " " << city.temp[i] << " " << city.name[i] << "\n";
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is a `city.name[4];` supposed to do? Why does a single city have 4 names? I suppose you want an array of 4 cities rather than one `City` with 4 names and 4 temperatures.  C-arrays are not really meant for beginners, look at `std::array` or `std::vector`, they are much simpler to work with

Comment: `city.name[4];` attempts to access the 5th element of a 4 element array and throws away the value it attempted to access. Accessing the 5th element (and any other out of bounds index) is undefined behavior.

Comment: `class City{ public:  string name; int temp[4]; };` **One** City has *one* name, and 4 seasonal temperatures.  That is what your class should look like -- it should "read" exactly how we would say it in English.  Then you create an array of these cities: `City allMyCities[4];`  -- Now you have 4 cities..

Comment: I would still fix the design. Your city class should represent a single city not 4 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good solution is to have a City-class with a name and a temperature and swap cities based on the order of the temperature with `std::sort`.

The easy fix for now is to use `std::swap` to swap the temperatures and at the  same time swap the names:

```
if(city.temp[j] > city.temp[j+1]){
    std::swap(city.temp[j], city.temp[j+1]);
    std::swap(city.name[j], city.name[j+1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work fine. Ill continue trying to understand exactly why this works and how to make use of it. Once again, Thank you!

Comment: Just know that std::swap does exactly as your three lines do, but with std::swap, I have 2 lines where otherwise I would have six.

Comment: Okay, I see. I managed to get it working using those six lines aswell. Thanks for the extremely clear answer and showing that I was atleast somewhat close with my three lines.